# OpenFileDialog: opening directories

Tags: c++, winforms, openfiledialog

I'd like to be able to select directories (in addition to single files) in the dialog. As it is now, when I click 'open' when the directory is selected, it descends into the directory, while I want it to return the path to the directory.

Additionally, how would I read such path? I don't see any property that would return the full path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to use a **[`FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx)** instead.

This dialog is designed to allow the user to select a folder. You can also enable the user to create a new folder, if you like, straight from the dialog box.

You shouldn't try and allow the user to select *either* a file *or* a folder from the same dialog. I don't think I've ever seen that done in an application. Consider how difficult it would be to distinguish between users expanding directories to locate files, and users who are attempting to select the directory itself. This is why two separate dialogs have been provided; choose the one that best suits your purposes.

---

As far as reading the full path to the file selected in an `OpenFileDialog`, the property you want is (somewhat confusingly) called [`FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx). The documentation explains that:

> The file name includes both the file path and the extension. If no files are selected, this method returns an empty string ("").

Or, if you're allowing multiple selection, you'll likely want to use the [`FileNames` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames.aspx) instead.

Comment: But I'd like to be able to select both single files and folders. Sorry, forgot that.

Comment: @Igor: That was added in an update. Please refresh the page to see it.

Comment: It's easiest, but not the best. The .NET built in FolderBrowserDialog does not automatically map to the new directory selection dialog introduced in Windows Vista and Windows 7, which is the biggest disadvantage of using it. Personally I use this wrapper instead, www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/

Comment: I am required to make a single dialog, as bad as it might sound. Though it didn't really startle me; I believe I've seen such behaviour in programs.

Comment: @Igor: And how does it know the difference? How do you expand a folder without selecting it? And how do you *select* a folder without simply expanding it? I can't imagine how this might work. If you wanted, you could have the user select an arbitrary file, and then just ignore the filename returned. But that seems particularly non-intuitive.